# Comprehensive treatments of the prohibition of bribery

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, gifts

I would like to educate myself about the nature and scope of the Biblical prohibition of "bribery" ("*Shochad*") and any associated Rabbinic prohibitions, as well as any derived ethical principles. I am interested in the basic application to judges as well as any applications (if they exist) that extend beyond the one to judges.

Are there any books that provide a comprehensive treatment of this prohibition and associated ethical principles?

Alternatively, what collection of sources should one study to get an overview of all the types of situations in which this prohibition and any derived ethical principles apply?

Comment: Choshen Mishpat 9 seems relevant

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a good start. I'm also interested in applications to non-Judges (if they exist).

Comment: The preceding siman which also discusses judges throws in behavioral guidelines for any parness hatzibur, and the Bach there that the achronim on the page quote about a judge who buys his position actually makes a limud from the cohen gadol. But the lav of shochad shochad, and the esei of mah ani bichinam seem to only apply to judges, as brought in shulchan aruch. The famous Rambam in pirkei avos notwithstanding.

Comment: Wait. That's not true. The ramma extends the judges laws to witnesses too. But that's it.

Comment: @user6591 Sorry; not famous enough for this *am haaretz*. Which *Rambam* in *Pirkei Avot*?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Maybe in the fourth perek? The one people use against kollel. Where the Rambam goes through all the famous Talmudic personalities who were poor but still didn't take money from the community. That one is about the mah ani bichinam though, not your shochad question. But they are somewhat related.

Comment: I have expanded the scope of the question to include derived ethical principles.

Comment: There is something also related. Just hit me. Chanifa. If i remember correctly it is described as shochad and applicable to anybody. But i might not be remembering correctly.

Comment: Re judges, see R. Zalman Nechemia's book משפט ערוך (which is on hebrewbooks.org). Re ethical principles, do you mean things that are found in mussar seforim (like the first section of Michtav Me'eliyahu on free will)?

Comment: @Matt, Re ethical: yes, or for example, if there are applications in business ethics

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.aspaklaria.info/300_SHIN/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%97%D7%93.htm) brings sources from

Torah, Mechilta, Sifri, Bavli, Yerushalmi, a selection of midrashim, Targum Yonason, Mishne Torah, Rabbeinu Yonah, Droshos HoRan, Menoras Hameor, Maharal, Kli Yokor, Malbim, Sefas Emes, Chochmoh Umussar and Reb Yerucham.